# Pareto Front algorithm?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to find the non-dominated solutions of two vectors of random numbers, so that I can plot the Pareto frontier. Here's my code, but I'm currently very stuck so any help with where to go from here would be greatly appreciated :)

```
x=rand(113,1)
y=rand(113,1)
x=sort(x, 'descend')
v=[x,y]
for i=1:113
    m=max(v(i,2))
        if v(i,2) > m
        n=max(v(i,2))
    end 
 end
```

Comment: Paste the algorithm in pseudo-code. Clarify carefully which curve or graph result you want to reproduce.

Comment: @hypfco Well we want to extract the Pareto frontier, which would be the set of non-dominated solutions and would ideally be non-convex. So, what I would want to do is for each x entry, check the value of each y entry and it would qualify as a non-dominated solution if the value of that y entry was greater than the maximum of ones that had come before it. And I would want to plot any non-dominated solutions that I found.

Comment: I fail to see any solution solving in your code, so hardly a plot in here will be any close to a Pareto frontier, or what you are seeking. Unless you are just looking for sketching point inside a plot, which dont require any code at all, even Matlab is required for such.