# Pareto front matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector

I have this code that is supposed to be plotting the Pareto frontier for my data, but only does in some cases. For background, the Pareto frontier is the set of all non-dominated solutions, which are the points that maximize each function. Any help troubleshooting?

```
x=cost;
y=portscores;
v=[x,y];
v=sortrows(v,1, 'descend');
x=v(:,1);
y=v(:,2);
count = 0 ;
n_vect = zeros(1,[]);
b_vect = zeros(1,[]);
for i=2:113
       m=max(v(1:i-1,2));
          if v(i,2) > m 
           n=(v(i,2));
           b=(v(i,1));

           n_vect = [n_vect,n];
           b_vect = [b_vect, b];

     end
 end
 scatter(x,y)
 hold on
 plot(b_vect, n_vect)
 xlabel('Overall Cost')
 ylabel('Overall Portfolio Scores')
 title('Pareto Frontier')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pareto Front algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036067/pareto-front-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're plotting out the data from human viewing there's no point in optimising the code. So just use the naive O(N squared) algorithm. Iterate through, then each point dominates the points it is superior to in both x and y, so set a flag. Then iterate through again to get the front, which is the unflagged points.